# Distribution provisioning profile still expire even after clicking the renew button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

my App's Distribution provisioning profile is expired, and a "renew" button appears next to it, but nothing happen upon clicking on it except it takes me to the Development provisioning profile page. The status for the Distribution provisioning profile remain expired after clicking the renew button. I want to renew it, does anybody have any idea about this.

Comment: Also when i tries to renew the distribution provisioning profile from the xcode's organizer, i got the following error message:  No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action, log yourself and follow the steps in order to renew your developer program.
After that, you can download the provisioning profile from your provisioning portail and set it in XCode by dragging it on the XCode app icon.
Remove the old one and it will be good.
Works for me :)

Comment: What a pain! I have 60 apps that all expired at the same time!